# Standard fact in knot theory

Tags: knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

In "Knots and Links in Spatial Graphs" (Journal of Graph Theory, vol.7 1983, 445-453), Conway and Gordon write :

"Now it is a standard fact in knot theory, not hard to prove, that any two spatial embeddings of $\Gamma$ are equivalent under the equivalence relation generated by moves of the form: ambiant isotopy to regular projection position followed by a change of crossing from over to under (a crossing change)."

Here $\Gamma$ is a finite graph, and a spatial embedding is a tame (polygonal) embedding into Euclidean space.

I am not sure of the exact meaning of this sentence, and would like to have some references where this would be stated and proved.

Comment: See "Reidemeister moves."

Comment: The core idea is that they're saying if you let the graph pass through itself any two spatial embeddings of $\Gamma$ are equivalent. You can do the passing-through-itself by taking diagrams and performing crossing changes. For knots, there's a standard argument that every knot is equivalent to the unknot after doing crossing changes in a diagram. Graphs are trickier because they might not be planar, unlike the unknot.